# String enumerations in swift 2.1

Tags: swift2

I am reading [swift 2.1 iBook](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148) about enumeration

The example :

```
enum CompassPoint: String {
  case North, South, East, West
}
```

gives me

```
<stdin>:3:8: error: enum cases require explicit raw values when the raw type is not integer literal convertible
case North, South, East, West
```

[demo](http://swiftstub.com/178608967/?v=gm)

I am not sure if documentation is outdated or some issue with compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the [online compiler](http://swiftstub.com/) you're using because it's in Swift 1.2 by default and you're using Swift 2 code.

There's a "Swift 1.2" button in the lower right corner of the site page, change it to "Swift 2 (beta)" and the error will disappear.